# How do I fix a random amount of for-loop?

Tags: arrays, swift, animation, sprite-kit, infinite-loop

I am creating a game (space shooter) using SpriteKit. Currently adding animations to the game. When explosions spawn, the animation loops at an X number of times (its really random). Sometimes it will loop 3 times and sometimes up to 10 times. The screen ends up being filled up with meaningless explosion animations.

I used to have a simple fade in/fade out animation which was working fine, but have finally upgraded to something smoother. I introduced a for loop and it has given me this issue. i also tried using a while loop with no avail. I have tried using the animation without a sequence but that doesn't fix anything either.

```
func spawnExplosion(spawnPosition: CGPoint) {

    var explosion = SKSpriteNode()

    textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "explosion")

    for i in 1...textureAtlas.textureNames.count {

        let name = "explosion\(i).png"
        textureArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: name))
        print(i)
    }

    explosion = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "explosion1.png" )
    explosion.setScale(0.6)
    explosion.position = spawnPosition
    explosion.zPosition = 3
    self.addChild(explosion)
    print(textureAtlas.textureNames.count)

    //explosion animation-action
    let explosionAnimation = SKAction.repeat(SKAction.animate(with: textureArray, timePerFrame: 0.05), count: 1)
    let delete = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let explosionSequence = SKAction.sequence([explosionSound, explosionAnimation, delete])
    explosion.run(explosionSequence)

}
```

The expected result is, when the function is called, the animation should run through ONCE and delete itself. Instead, it runs once up to 10 or so times.

Comment: You have a global array that you are not clearing.  Every time you call spawn explosion, you add to your animation

Comment: @Knight0fDragon, Good eye catching this. I missed it at first glance. You should post this as an answer including code to empty the array at the beginning of the function. Then the OP can accept it and we can up-vote it.

Comment: @DuncanC  Armando is new, I would prefer he wrote his own answer with my tip to help him with the rep.

Comment: Fair enough, but you should still post your response as an answer so the OP can accept it, and so others know that the question has been answered.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon i thought it was something like this. At some point theres multiple instances of 'i' and all the explosions get in sync with each other. How do I make it so that each explosion has it's own instance?

Comment: You can make your texture array local, or create your texture array once in the beginning and avoid having to recreate a nee array every time.  Whatever you do, create it as an answer for yourself.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon wow thanks, I fixed the problem. I made the texture array local. I didn't realize it would be an issue. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Knight0fDragon, I was able to fix this issue by making the texture array local within the function. Now each explosion has it's own instance.

```
    func spawnExplosion(spawnPosition: CGPoint) {
    var explosion = SKSpriteNode()
    var textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas()
    var textureArray = [SKTexture]()

    textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "explosion")

    for i in 1...textureAtlas.textureNames.count {

        let name = "explosion\(i).png"
        textureArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: name))
    }

    explosion = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "explosion1.png" )
    explosion.setScale(0.6)
    explosion.position = spawnPosition
    explosion.zPosition = 3
    self.addChild(explosion)

    //explosion animation-action
    let explosionAnimation = SKAction.repeat(SKAction.animate(with: textureArray, timePerFrame: 0.05), count: 1)
    let delete = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let explosionSequence = SKAction.sequence([explosionSound, explosionAnimation, delete])
    explosion.run(explosionSequence)

}
```